# horizontal scrolling script

Tags: javascript

i need horizontal scrolling script in javascript, but don't have much time to write it, so could you give me some links where i can find it?
could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of such widgets provided by a bunch of different javascript libraries.

- [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/)
- [Prototype/Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)
- JSMadeEasy as posted by FacilityDerek above.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) scripts:

- The first is a scrolling menu: [Horizontal Scrolling Menu made with CSS and jQuery](http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/) Example [here](http://valums.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/menu/final.htm)
- The second is a scrolling pane [jScrollHorizontalPane](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jscrollhorizontalpane) example [here](http://threeformed.com/labs/jScrollHorizontalPane/examples/basicScroller.html)
- Here is a more simple one also using jQuery: [simplyScroll v1](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html)
- If what you want is more of a news ticker, you might find this interesting: [liScroll (a jQuery News Ticker made easy) 1.0](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)